# Type / Notation of a distance in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've been reading a book and I stumbled upon a notation that I don't understand. Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. If $A$ is a partition of $X$, then we may consider the metric space $(A, d|_{A \times A})$. What does the distance $d|_{A \times A}$ represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d$ is a function $d: X\times X\to \mathbb R$ and $A\times A$ is a subset of $X\times X$, so $d|_{A\times A}$ denote the restriction of $d$ to $A\times A$. That is,

$$d_{A\times A} (x, y) = d(x, y),\ \ \ \forall (x, y)\in A\times A.$$